¿Porque el efecto parallax no funciona para ios?
Tengo diseñado una invitación web de XV años, le he agregado el efecto parallax, el problema que tengo es que en dispositivos con ios la imagen se pixelea mucho, no toma su tamaño al 100%, con el sistema Android me funciona bien, habrá alguna una solución.


#portada2{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../image/portada1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 3%, 100% 5%, 100% 100%, 51% 97%, 0 100%, 0 5%);
  }



Link para ver invitación:
http://xvgold.angeldesign82.com/

Buenas, yo veo la mayoría de imagenes pixeleadas y estoy en Chrome directamente. Al revisar las fuentes, las imagenes parecen haber sido comprimidas y de mala manera. Estás seguro que no es problema de que la imagen haya sido mal comprimida? la imagen galeria 5, se vee bien en grande, pero mal con zoom por ejemplo. imagenGaleria5

Generalmente, el método de tener las imagenes bien, sería tener diferentes portes y calidades para los diferentes dispositivos en los cuales serán mostrados, y cargar esa imagen en dicho dispositivo.
